# counting instances of a number but only when following another that has been repeated ex. 0,0,0,0,1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to count a number in excel but only when it is proceeded by another that has been repeated 4 times.  The numbers are only 0 and 1 for example **0,0,0,0,1**.  Because 1 was preceeded by 0 4 times the *count* would be 1.
I have found numerous references to countif and countifs but none of those would be looking at or checking the **frequency of 0** to determine whether or not to count.

Comment: You'll need to provide either a more specific rule, or more examples (including multiple variations) in order to figure out what you really want. Examples of what you have tried, multiple instances of original data, and what you expect for results will also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

To get just the 0,0,0,0,1 combos:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A1040001,0,A2:A1040002,0,A3:A1040003,0,A4:A1040004,0,A5:A1040005,1)
```

To get just the 1,1,1,1,0 combos:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A1040001,1,A2:A1040002,1,A3:A1040003,1,A4:A1040004,1,A5:A1040005,0)
```

To get both:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A1040001,{0,1},A2:A1040002,{0,1},A3:A1040003,{0,1},A4:A1040004,{0,1},A5:A1040005,{1,0}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer is  supplemental in case you later need counts "(including multiple variations)", as hinted at in Mr. Rosenfeld's comment. This formula placed in B2 will give counts of Zeroes immediately preceded by ones: =IF(IF(A2=0,COUNTIF(A$1:A1,1)-SUM(B$1:B1),"")>0,IF(A2=0,COUNTIF(A$1:A1,1)-SUM(B$1:B1),""),""). This one,  placed in C2 will flip the script-ones immediately preceded by zeros:=IF(IF(A2=1,COUNTIF(A$1:A1,0)-SUM(C$1:C1),"")>0,IF(A2=1,COUNTIF(A$1:A1,0)-SUM(C$1:C1),""),"").

Answer (score 0):

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Y87:AR87 = 0,COLUMN(Y87:AR87)),IF(Y87:AR87 <> 
                     RANGE                  TO          LOOK
0,COLUMN(Y87:AR87)))4,1))
           AT      HOW MANY ZEROS TO COUNT

RE: The question I had thanks for your kind responses, sorry I had this formula on an old sheet and thought I'd give it a try. It wasn't easy to find took a while have found it useful hope it is of some use to someone.

*by the way if your data is't in a row but a column instead then you will need change the column formula to row formula. for example.

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Y87:AR87=0,ROW(Y87:AR87)),IF(Y87:AR87<>0,ROW(Y87:AR87)))=4,1))

*also remember this is a "range" formula it will need special key combination shift + cntrl + enter "all three at once"
Thanks again,

Comment: The text editor changed things around formula at the top should have said =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(Y87:AR87=0,COLUMN(Y87:AR87)),IF(Y87:AR87<>0,COLUMN(Y87:AR87)))4,1))